# How can I access property of subclass in an array of its parent class

Tags: typescript, oop

I'm working on an implementation of Chess. I have a class for each piece and a general class from which these inherit. I am storing all pieces in an array of the parent class, `Piece`.

In some instances, I want to access a specific piece from this array and reference a property that is on it but not its parent, `Piece`. How can I go about doing this?

I have:

```
interface IAllPieces {
    [key: string] : Piece[],
}

myFunction(allPieces: IAllPieces) {
    const kingsideRook: Rook = allPieces[...index/code that finds the Rook that I am looking for];
    const hasRoomMoved: boolean = kingsideRook.hasMoved;
}
```

Here, `hasMoved` is a property of the child class, `Rook`, but not its parent class, `Piece`.

I currently see an error, `Type 'Piece' is missing the following properties from type 'Rook': <rook specific properties here>`. If I instead have `const kingsideRook: Rook = ...`, I see `Property 'hasMoved' does not exist on type 'Piece'.`

Comment: Consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) so others can demonstrate the issue for themselves.

Comment: If *you* know it's a `Rook` you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) like `allPieces[someIndex] as Rook`, but if you're wrong about that the compiler won't catch it.  It's usually better to do something the compiler can verify, but I'd need a more fleshed out example before I could suggest something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript thinks every value of `allPieces` is an instance of `Piece` because that's how it's typed. It may be a subclass of `Piece`, but typescript isn't going to know that without some help.

But you can add a conditional to test if the instance is a `Rook` and then treat it like a `Rook` in the body of that conditional. This keeps type safety since you only run methods that only exist on `Rook` once you have verified at runtime it really is of type `Rook`.

```
const kingsideRook = allPieces[rookId];
if (kingsideRook instanceof Rook) {
  const hasRoomMoved: boolean = kingsideRook.hasMoved;
} else {
  console.error(`something went wrong. ${rookId} is not a Rook.`)
}
```